# Triggered background color change doesn't fire

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Why doesn't this getElementsByTagName trigger work, but the getElementById will.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2ugf3otw/)

SCRIPT

```
<script>
function trigger1()
  {document.getElementsByTagName("td").style.backgroundColor="green";}
function trigger2() {document.getElementById("apple").style.backgroundColor="green";}
</script>
```

HTML

```
<table width="90" border="1">
<tr><td>a</td><td>b</td></tr>
<tr><td>d</td><td id="apple">e</td></tr>
</table><br>
<input type="button" onclick="trigger1()" value="change TD backgrounds">
    <br><br>
<input type="button" onclick="trigger2()" value="Change E background">
```

Comment: `getElementsByTagName` returns an array. `document.getElementsByTagName("td")[0]` for the first element.

Comment: @JSuar Matt was just slightly quicker on the draw. Thanks though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

getElementsByTagName returns an array.

You could make the background of each array item green by iterating through the array like such:

```
tdElements = document.getElementsByTagName("td");
for(var key in tdElements) { tdElements[key].style.backgroundColor="green"; }
```

jQuery example:

```
$('td').each(function() { $(this).css('background-color', 'green'); });
```

Comment: Would have thought that it simply would have applied the styling to each element of the array without having to iterate over each one. But ok, I get it. Thanks for clarification.